# byte[] over 3MB comes up NULL in API C#

Tags: c#, .net, api, file

I have an desktop application written in .NET 4.7.2 that uses an API to upload files to SharePoint.

This is the call to the API

```cs
var responseMessage = this
                      .Client
                      .PostAsync("/Upload", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                      .Result;

if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    throw new Exception("Save to Sharepoint Failed");

return responseMessage;
```

The content type and the `byte[]` are all good in the file object, it successfully uploads a file less than 3MB just fine.

The API .NET 4.7.1
Once it gets here the request.doc object, if over ~3MB then the request.doc will be NULL and as such the upload will fail.

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Route("Upload")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> SaveFileToSharePointStream([FromBody] SharepointFileUploadRequest request)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(request.doc))
    {
        var result = await _sharepointBll.SaveFileToSharePointStream(request.newFileName, ms, request.folderPath, request.fileTags);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I tried adding in the web.config on both the client and the server to no avail.

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits>
        <headerLimits>
          <add header="Content-type" sizeLimit="30000000" />
        </headerLimits>
      </requestLimits>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

I think the issue might be with `String.Content()`, but I can't seem to find a way to increase the amount of data I can pass to it.

Comment: PostAsync() takes time (thus Async), you must wait until the post completed before IsSuccessStatusCode can provide a reliable value.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Graph API? If so, note that there 2 methods, [one for small files, up to 4MB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-put-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and [one for any file size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0). Maybe you're using the first one, so you're hiting the limit of 4MB

Comment: I am not using Graph API

Comment: Just wondering, what are you hoping limiting the value length of the `Content-Type` header to 30 megabytes will achieve?

Comment: I was thinking that the limit was too low, and I needed to define higher. I was trying to raise the ceiling, not lower the limit.

Comment: @HansPassant could you provide an example of what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the api in the config I had to add `maxRequestLength`

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" executionTimeout="1000" maxRequestLength="30720" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing `new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(file)`, you can try by passing the `SharepointFileUploadRequest` as parameter from your given code.